# Best way to write a function that randomly takes definition from list of functions?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction, programming

I want to define a function based on a random choice from a list of possible functions.

For example, suppose the possible functions are `{Sqrt,Log}`. Then I want to define `f[x]` to be a (randomly chosen) one of `f[x_]=Sqrt[x]` and `f[x_]:=Log[x]`

What is a good way to do this? (and have it work with user defined functions in the list, like `{Sqrt,Log,x^2+x}`

---

My feeling is that I should make a function that takes a list of functions as an input, and randomly chooses one of them. I have an example of this below, but I have three concerns/issues with the below code:

1. using `?fun1` gives `fun1=Log`, not `fun1=Log[x]`

   - I don't know how(/whether) this matters, but something nags at me that it does
2. If I want a function that is either `f[x_]:=Sqrt[x]` `f[x_]:=Log[x+1]`, I don't know how to incorporate this "+1" part
3. I should probably be using `:=` not `=` in the example code below

I imagine 1 and 3 can likely be corrected by some small tweak to the code, whereas for 2 all I can think of is using `Which`, but this seem unwieldy for long lists of possible functions.

I don't know how to go about correcting this hence my question.

Example code:

```
SeedRandom[10];
chooseFun[listFun_] := 
  Module[{randVal}, randVal = RandomInteger[{1, Length[listFun]}];
   listFun[[randVal]]
   ];
fun1 = chooseFun[{Sqrt, Log}];
fun2 = chooseFun[{Sqrt, Log}];
```

---

Edit: Note: Its not a requirement that the function take a list of functions as an input. I would be okay, say, defining `ListOfFunctions` before calling SeedRandom in the below code.

Also, an additional concern/question: Normally when we do something like `f[x_]:=x^2` it assigns the RHS to the LHS. But in the case here I dont want to assign the LHS to the RHS, but the something based on the output of the RHS. (Sorry if I have not explained this well)

---

Edit 2: Heres another attempt I have made. This one uses a function that defines another function (based on a name that is the input).

- Is this a good approach?
- Note here `?test` gives `test[x$_] := listFun[x$][[randNum$61000]]`

.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[10];
listFun[x_] := {Sqrt[x], Log[x + 1]};
chooseRandFunc[name_] := Module[{randNum},
  randNum = RandomInteger[{1, Length[listFun[x]]}];
  name[x_] := listFun[x][[randNum]]
  ];
chooseRandFunc[test]
```

**Edit 3:** It seems the question was not clear, so I went back to try to clarify. Sorry to the existing answers

Comment: why not simply  `ClearAll[chooseFun]; chooseFun=RandomChoice`?

Comment: @kglr Honestly, I was not aware of that function. Does `chooseFun[x]` evaluate properly though, in particular if one of the options is a user defined function like `Log[x+1]` or `x^2_x` as opposed to a system one like `Log` or `Sqrt`? (I ask because I usually think about `f[x_]:=x^2` as saying "take x^2 and replace x by whatever is given", but `chooseFun=RandomChoice` doesn't take an input which confuses me.)

Comment: you need to use it as `chooseFunb[{Sqrt, Log}]@xx` or as `fa =chooseFunb[{Sqrt, Log}]; fa@x`

Comment: alternatively, you can define `choseFun` as `ClearAll[chooseFun];
chooseFun := RandomChoice[{Sqrt, Log}];` Then `chooseFun[t]` gives `Sqrt[t]` or `Log[t]` at each invocation.

Comment: @kglr Sorry I am not understanding stuff, and/or I have not explained my question well. First, why `chooseFunb` in the earlier comment (i.e. why is there a "b" there?). Second, with `ClearAll[chooseFun] chooseFun := RandomChoice[{Sqrt, Log}];`, `chooseFun[t]` would (potentially) switch from `Sqrt` to `Log` on different evaluations, wouldn't it?

Comment: I do think your first suggestion of `ClearAll[chooseFun]; chooseFun=RandomChoice` works, however, if I want user defined functions like `x^2+x` to be possible, I need to do `userFun[x_]:=x^2+x; chooseFun=[RandomChoice[{Sqrt,userFun}]` instead of chooseFun=[RandomChoice[{Sqrt,x^2+x}]`, because with the latter if `x^2+x` is chosen, `chooseFun[2]` gives `(x+x^2)[2]` (perhaps mathematica doesn't treat `x^2+x` as a function?)

Comment: `chooseFunb` was a typo; it should have been `chooseFun`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[10];
```

Use pure functions and RandomChoice

```
listFun = {E^# - 1 &, Sqrt, Log[# + 1] &, #^2 &, Sin, Cos};

func[x_] := RandomChoice[listFun][x]

Plot[Evaluate[f = func[x]], {x, 0, 2}, PlotLabel -> f]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@DeleteDuplicates@Table[func[x], 3], {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: This looks really nice, however I have an issue (sorry if I didn't explain my question well), `func[x]` can change from being `Cos` to `Sin` from one evaluation to the next. **I don't want that to be possible**. Specifically, I want a function, `func[x_]:=`, that becomes one of the functions in `listFun`, and once it becomes one of those functions it no longer changes. Does that make sense? (I think changing `:=` to `=` might fix this though?)

Comment: Perhaps another way of saying this is as follows: With the code you have provided `?func` gives `func[x_] := RandomChoice[listFun][x]`. What I want it to be is `func[x_]:=Cos[x]`, or an equivalent version of that (not need to be `Cos`, I just use `Cos` as example since that is the first thing you `func` evaluate to). Then, if I have `func1[x_] := RandomChoice[listFun][x]`, `func2[x_] := RandomChoice[listFun][x]`, `func1` might be `Sin`,`Cos`, etc, and `func2` can possibly be a different one, and so on

Comment: Yes `Set` would give a fixed result. That is what `Evaluate` does in the plots.